Visa curtailed problem pops up every time I try to enter the UK
I can't find a similar example to mine so I'm writing this question.
I only hold a Romanian passport and I used to study in the UK for about 1 year (post-brexit) on a student visa in the UK and then I transferred to a US university, because I was no longer a student at a UK university obviously my visa was curtailed, the issue I have is every time I try to use e-gates in the UK I always get the assistance needed message at which point I am sent to manual review, where I am temporarily told to go into a holding area until they can confirm that I did in-fact transfer universities to the US (after I show them my F1 visa)and did not commit some crime and after I am allowed in. This isn't detrimental however it always adds 30minutes to a hour from landing to entering the UK and I was just wondering if anyone has any information on when this curtailment no longer appears on my record or if there's anyway to get this issue sorted so I can begin using e-gates again.

It's not a full answer so I wont post it as one. You can request whatever information the UK Border Force has on you through a subject access request. Maybe this will contain useful info? https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration

@Ozzy thanks for the recommendation, I have submitted a request and will see if it provides any helpful information.

Following the UK’s general advice to visa-free nationals who have a previous ‘problem’ and applying for a visa for your next trip is an option to reset your history.
